# I am considering closing a question that was downvoted. Can I suspend it instead of deleting it?

Tags: discussion

It is really self-explanatory. Just see my last question that was downvoted as a reference

see

question:
Can I ask other stack overflow members to consider remving their downvote after a post has been deleted?

Comment: We can't undo voting on deleted posts.

Comment: Or rather _deleted posts cannot be voted upon_.

Answer (score 3):

Downvotes will not be deleted from the question, but a deleted question does not count in your reputation, either good or bad.

They do count when the system determines if you need to be question banned because of asking lots of bad questions.

Comment: maybe we can speak later about this

Answer (score 3):

No, because you can't vote on deleted posts. And many users can't even see them.

Why are you deleting these posts in the first place? From your previous question, it sounds like you want to "suspend" it until you edit it to make it good. Well, why don't you post a good question in the first place, instead of posting a bad question and editing to make it good?

Comment: AFAIK, the OP can edit a self-deleted post.